# What’s a good way to carry a kid’s bike on an otherwise full bakfiets?

Tags: rack, cargo, children

I have a Workcycles [KR8](http://www.workcycles.com/products/child-transport-bicycles/workcycles-kr8) bakfiets and the 3yo just got his first [pedal bike](https://woombikes.com/products/2?ls=en).

[image]

[image]

We wanted to take him and his bike for a fifteen minute ride to the park where he could ride by himself, but chucking his bike into the front damages the box on the bakfiets, and won’t work at all when his infant sister comes along for the ride.

Has anyone seen a system for mounting kids’ bikes on a rear rack, or maybe off the sides of the box of a bakfiets? A [Follow Me](https://family-cycling.com/93r5Wql5-familycycling-english/) does more than we need and is quite expensive.

Comment: Have a look for "Trail Gator" - may be more in your price bracket.

Comment: A Trail Gator isn’t really what I want either—I don’t want the kid to ride the bike, just want to carry the bikes to where we can ride.

Comment: Thought was you can tow the bike without the child on it.

Comment: I only ever took this for a test ride but it seemed to work: [balance bike on rear rack with rear child seat](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/40541/7309). Pedals would make it a little harder but not having the child seat on top would make it easier.

Comment: Your 3 year old starts cycling with such a fantastic bike! That must be quite a joy.

Comment: It's a pretty common problem. Have you asked around in some of the bike shops that not just sell bakfietsen but are also a bit more specialised?

Comment: @gschenk You can't dawdle on a bike with pedals like you can on a balance bike, so it cuts 2/3 off our travel time in the morning. Worth every penny! I have to take the bakfiets in for service soon actually, so I will ask my local specialist cargo bike dealer if they know of anything.

Comment: I would suggest some sort of tow-behind scheme.  There are several commercially-available schemes, plus you could probably cobble something up -- just somehow lash the front wheel of the kid's bike to the back wheel of that truck.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 - In the bin, forks over the front edge, with the front wheel removed and stowed inside bin.  Front two kids won't fit, and you'll have to mind that the steering isn't limited on the cargo bike.  Advantage, second bike goes on the other side.

[image]

Option 1b- same as above but hang it on the outside of the frame.  A short support that crosses the top of the bin would provide somewhere to hook the frame onto.  Pictured facing backward, but might go better the other way.   The inboard pedal could be a problem.

[image]

---

Option 2 - Extend the bin's frame and lean bikes on that.  Downside, its wide and involved modding your cargo bike.  Some kind of insert into the end of tubes might be adequate.  Upside, still carry 3 kids.

[image]

---

Option 3 - Add a rear rack (yellow) and strap the bike there

[image]

---

Option 4 - No picture.  Put the bike in a backpack like a tramping/hiking frame pack and carry it that way.

---

Option 0 - Three years is probably a bit small to be riding on the road, but riding a bit on the footpath may be ideal - depends on your location.  I like this one!

Upside, more room in the bin.  Kid gets exercise before you get there.  Sets a good example

Downside, you'll have to think for him while riding, so it will be extra slow.  Could double/triple your travel time.

[image]

All these answers will require some level of padding in appropriate places.

Comment: Option 1 is no good because it requires disassembling the kids bike, and rules out the carrying of the infant. Option 0 is explicitly what I’m trying to avoid. Option 1b or option 3 (but maybe slung along the sides pannier style, rather than bungeed across the top) is what I’m looking for a prebuilt solution for, I don’t have a metalworking shop handy.

Comment: @RobertAtkins A prebuilt solution for a rather uncommon style of bike is going to be very uncommon.  Are you prepared to put two notches in each side of your bin?  If so, then two broomstick handles across the top could be a starter.

Comment: @RobertAtkins the only reason for taking the front wheel off in option 1 was to stop it from fouling the cargo bike's steering.     Another option might be to simply wrap the bike in a blanket or some other padding, and put it in the bin wrapped up.

Comment: Depending on where you are, bakfietsen aren’t that uncommon . I did think there might be some rear rack solution about though.

Comment: @RobertAtkins do let us know what you find and do - its fascinating.  I'd only see a cargo bike once every 2~3 years.

Comment: When I lived in Amsterdam they were wholly unremarkable, and even here in Berlin I’d be surprised if I didn’t see at least another one daily.

Comment: +1 for the effort taken for photoshopping option 0

Comment: Be careful with option 1b. With just a bit of braking the children might hit the vibe with their faces. (Haven't seen people using those seat belts in a bakfiets yet.)